# RegEx for placeholder (mmddyyyy) with no particular order

Tags: c#, .net, regex, formatting

I have a string that looks like this: *myFile{ddmmyyyy}.csv* and a C# DateTime object. I need to substitute the correct day/month/year from the DateTime into the string. However the problem lies in the fact that the parameters can be in a different order AND not all of them might be present.

e.g. All of these are valid use cases:

- myFile{ddmmyyyy}.csv
- myFile{mmddyyyy}.csv
- myFile{mmyyyy}.csv
- myFile{yyyymm}.csv

Any suggestions/ideas on the regex that I could use to find/substitute these would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Just to be clear, I get the actual string that has "mmddyyyy" in there (characters, not the corresponding numbers) where "mm" needs to be substituted for the month number (10 representing October, for example) for the DateTime received.

Comment: Are you sure you need a regex and not ``string.Format()``?

Comment: string.Format() will not suffice as I receive a literal string like "myFile{ddmmyyyy}.csv" along with a DateTime and need the result to look like "myFile22102013.csv", but I don't know in advance which order the mmddyyyy will be in or even if any of them will be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static string FormatFilename(string pattern, DateTime dt)
{
    return Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\{(.*)\}", match =>
    {
        string format = match.Result("$1").Replace("m", "M");
        return dt.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    });
}
```

Then just call it like this (for example):

```
string input = "myFile{ddmmyyyy}.csv";
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 1, 4);
string filename = FormatFilename(input, dt);
```

**Update**

It *is* possible to do this without a regex:

```
private static string FormatFilename(string pattern, DateTime dt)
{
    return string.Format(pattern.Replace("{", "{0:").Replace("mm", "MM"), dt);
}
```

But I think the other version is cleaner and more resilient to input variation.

Answer (score 0):

would \w+\d+.csv work for you?

Comment: No, unfortunately not - this is a bit too broad for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just match

```
@"myFile\d{8}.csv"
```

And use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse it (use the overload that accepts an array of formats)

Comment: I'm not sure how the above would work as I receive a literal string like "myFile{ddmmyyyy}.csv" along with a DateTime and need the result to look like "myFile22102013.csv", as per my comment above, but the actual params order/number within the {} varies?